# Standardization and inclusion of intercept in sparse lasso GLM

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, lasso-regression, standardized, sgl

I found some problems while practicing the sparse group lasso method using the `cvSGL` function forom the `SGL` package.

My questions are as follows:

1. Looking at the code for `SGL:::center_scale`, it doesn't seem to consider the sample size of the data.

```
SGL:::center_scale
#Output
function (X, standardize) {
    means <- apply(X, 2, mean)
    X <- t(t(X) - means)
    X.transform <- list(X.means = means)
    if (standardize == TRUE) {
        var <- apply(X, 2, function(x) (sqrt(sum(x^2))))
        X <- t(t(X)/var)
        X.transform$X.scale <- var
    }
    else {
        X.transform$X.scale <- 1
    }
    return(list(x = X, X.transform = X.transform))
}
```

Therefore, the sample standard deviation of the predicted variable is measured somewhat larger.

Is my understanding correct that this may cause the coefficients to be excessively large?

2. whether the model can be estimated by SGL package with intercept term (or constant term)

The `SGL` package does not seem to provide a function for estimating by including a intercept term.

In `cvFit[["fit"]]`, I can see only the beta of the predict variables according to the `lambda`'s except for the constant term. The value of `cvFit[["fit"]][["intercept"]]` is the mean of the `y` variable.

It can be estimated by adding `1` to first column  of predict variable `X`, but in this case, it is expected to cause problems in centering and standardizing predict variables.

In addition, the `SPG` package seems to add a penalty to all predict variables. Even if the estimation is performed by adding `1` to the first column of the explanatory variable `X` as described above, the constant term may be estimated as `0`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've taken the liberty to add additional formatting to your question and changed the title in the hopes of increasing the visibility of your question and attract a possible answer. While it is always recommended to name the package this question seems more related to the problem of GLM lasso regression, and questions that may be easily answered by experienced users without knowledge of the package. As such i think LASSO better describes the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, this seems bad to me. Running the code on inputs of different length results in different column variances in the result. For an input with `n` rows, the column variance of the result is `1 / (n - 1)`. It's *possible* this is accounted for elsewhere, [but I don't see it in the next obvious place to look](https://github.com/cran/SGL/blob/3f51a8d0b6a2aaf928f8793bff3028b1cb3977b2/R/SGLmain.R#L9), when `center_scale` is called.